System freezes after running setup.py (PJSIP)
I'm trying to create a SIP client using Raspberry Pi 2,I want to do it using PJSUA2 library for Python. I downloaded the git file for PJSIP project, ran ./configure, then I ran make dep && make && make install in PJSIP directory successfully. afterwards as mentioned in:
https://docs.pjsip.org/en/latest/pjsua2/building.html#building-python-swig-module
I tried running make command in ./pjsip-apps/src/swig/python, but every time I try to do so, the entire system freezes, any idea what should I do?
The last message it gives in terminal is:
python3 setup.py build
UserWarning: normalizing '2.14-dev' to '2.14-dev0'
warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))

